# Central Admin unexpected error

Tags: 2010, error, central-administration

I accidentally tried to enable a web app solution on the central admin web app. It errored and did not enable. I closed CA and now when I try to open I get an unexpected error when traced points to a feature that is in the solution I accidentally tried to enable.

How can I undo this mistake?

Comment: what exactly is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried manually retracting and uninstalling. Neither worked. What happened is part of the feature I attempted to enable had already started to change the CA masterpage and css. To fix this we had to work through all of the errors so the feature could deploy and then deactivate and retract.

Answer (score 1):

You can [Retract and Uninstall SharePoint Solution via Powershell by going to this link](http://snipplr.com/view/43124/)

or

can also [uninstall-all-sharepoint-2010-solutions-via-powershell/](http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/11/06/uninstall-all-sharepoint-2010-solutions-via-powershell/) if you don't know which solution you installed but its not recommended

or you can retract solution using STSADM by going to this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261799%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and then delete it [by going to this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261929%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried manually retracting and deleting the solution. It seems that when the feature tried to enable on CA it partially installed parts of the feature even though the feature errored and stopped. Is there a way to see or undo recent changes to CA files, or to revert CA to its factory setup?